# Validate API calls from a user that authenticated with Twitter

Tags: authentication, twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, access-token

I am implementing a Social Network authentication workflow, with a specific app, where on server side (left) there is a REST service to which the client (center) makes API calls. The goal is to validate on server side the authenticity of the user using Twitter API, i.e. the user first authenticates against Twitter, and then makes calls to a secure server, which must validate the API calls by means of a user_token included in the calls' parameters by the user. Have a look at next image:

[image]

STEPS:

1. The user connects to Twitter, and authenticates, asking for **user_token**
2. Twitter API returns an **app_user-id** (in the scope of the app) and a **user_token**.
3. The client sends an API call to server side with the **app_user-id**  and the **user_token**.
4. The server connects to Twitter asking for an **bearer_token** by sending the app **app_key** and **app_secret**.
5. Twitter API responds with a **bearer_token**.
6. The server tests with Twitter API the **user_token** received from the user in step 3 and the **bearer_token** just received in step 5.
7. Twitter API responds validating the user.
8. The server considers the call comes from a legitimate user and delivers the output of the call to the her/him.

Regarding this, I have a couple of questions:

- Is this a right way/protocol to validate user calls to the REST service on server side by using Twitter API authentication?

Thank you.